# Update specific field in series of collections firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How to update the username field in Firestore? I used the below code but not working:

Using: Flutter

```dart
final commentPostsSnapshot = await _firestore
            .collection("posts")
            .doc()
            .collection("comments")
            .where("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .get();

for (final doc in commentPostsSnapshot.docs) {
    await doc.reference.update({"username": "newUsername"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the [CollectionReference#doc()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html) method without passing any string argument, it means that an auto-generated ID is used. This means that you cannot create a path to the `comments` sub-collection since each time a new ID is generated. In order to query the `comments` sub-collection, you have to pass the ID of the document that contains that sub-collection. So you have to use the following code:

```
final commentPostsSnapshot = await _firestore
            .collection("posts")
            .doc("documentId") //
            .collection("comments")
            .where("uid", isEqualTo: user.uid)
            .get();
```

If you need to get all documents within **all** `comments` sub-collections, then you have to perform a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Here you can find the official documentation:

- https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html

Comment: Hey Yah. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?